# How to prove that the product of two congruence classes mod p are congruent to another product of congruence classes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Let $p$ be an odd prime, let $r_1, r_2,..., r_{p-1}$ be the integers $1, 2,..., p-1$ in any order. Prove that at least two of the numbers $1\cdot r_1, 2\cdot r_2, ..., (p-1)\cdot r_{p-1}$ are congruent modulo $p$.

Here's what I have noticed so far. I think this is likely true by working with cases of $p=5$ and $p=7$. I also noticed that:

$$\begin{align}1\cdot r_1&=r_1 \pmod p\\2\cdot r_2&=2r_2 \pmod p\\...  \\(p-2)\cdot r_{p-2}&=-2\cdot r_{p-2} \pmod p\\(p-1)\cdot r_{p-1}&=-r_{p-1} \pmod p\end{align}$$

I'm not sure where to go from here, or if I'm even on the right track. Would the best method be a direct proof or should I consider a proof by contradiction? Thanks for the help, and sorry for the inability to type subscripts in here better.

Comment: Assume they are different mod $p$. Then they are all non-zero remainders mod $p$. Multiply all of them together to get $(p-1)!r_1r_2...r_{p-1}=(p-1)!$. Therefore $(p-1)!=r_1r_2...r_{p-1}=1$ mod $p$. By Wilson's theorem $(p-1)!=-1$ mod $p$. Therefore $2(p-1)!=0$ mod $p$. This implies $p$ divides $2$. Contradiction.

Comment: That clears everything up. Thanks for the help and the edits!